# Disable links in WKWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, wkwebview

I want to load page in WKWebView, and then disable links in it. Most of the links are relative.

Tried with `webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler:` but new page is loaded before it's called and relative links don't appear if i use `navigationAction.request.URL` . Also tried with `UIDelegate`, and that didn't load at all.

Any ideas? Obj C is prefferable, but Swift is also ok.

EDIT:

OK, I'll rephrase the question a bit.

When user presses link I want to stop WKWebView to open it, and instead save that link to array. Maybe open it manually with loadrequest if certain conditions are met.

Code is simple

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *sURL = @"https://www.mytestingwebsite.com";
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:sURL];

    WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    [self addUserScriptsToUserContentController:theConfiguration.userContentController];

    WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:theConfiguration];
    webView.navigationDelegate = self;
    webView.UIDelegate = self;
    //webView.allowsLinkPreview = TRUE;

    NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    [webView loadRequest:nsrequest];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
}
```

They've used in WWDC 2014, video 206 `NSURL *selectedURL = navigationAction.request.URL;` to detect and disable external links. But that obviously isn't working for me. I've just added NSLog and breakpoint to test it.

Comment: Have you tried `webView.allowsLinkPreview = false`?

Comment: Tried it. But default value is false. If it's true, press hold works, but i want to disable it completely and open it manually if certain conditions are met.

Comment: show your code for identifying

Comment: I'm afraid you would be mis-using `webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler:`. Please show the code you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I couldn't come up with something smarter, I did it with javascript.

Basically, you load js file, look for container and links, and set `href="javascript:(void)"` for links you want.

Comment: How have you used this? can you explain with one example.

Answer (score 5):

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Swift.Void) {
    guard navigationAction.navigationType == .other || navigationAction.navigationType == .reload  else {
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
        return
    }
    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

Comment: With some javascript, links may keep type `.other`, which means `navigationType` is very unreliable.

Comment: Is there anything else that needs to be added? This function doesn't get called when I click on a link in my MKWebView.

Comment: It still falls backs to the allow case when the user clicks on a side panel menu or etc.

Comment: I like that solution, for now created with it simple filtering based on list of allowed urls, then I check host and scheme. Need to investigate though why there are so many different callbacks for WKNavigationDelegate and if it's possible that something slips through when implementing just this one - so watch out :D

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void)
{
    decisionHandler(navigationResponse.response.url?.absoluteString == mainLink ? .allow : .cancel)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come across with one solution to completely disable links including JavaScript.

I have used WKWebview in place of UIWebview to implement this.

Create one BOOL variable and set it YES in view did load.

```
allowLoad = YES;
```

Put this below code where you are loading URL to disable Java script.

```
WKPreferences *preferences = [[WKPreferences alloc] init];
preferences.javaScriptEnabled = NO;
WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
configuration.preferences = preferences;
self.webView =[[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) configuration:configuration];
self.webView.navigationDelegate = self;
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Your URL that you want to lead"]];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

Now add required delegate methods for WKNavigationDelegate to disable link -

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didStartProvisionalNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {
[MBProgressHUD showHUDWithText:SyLocalizedString(@"Loading", @"L10N comment TBD") addedTo:self.view];}

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {
[MBProgressHUD hideAllProgressHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];
allowLoad = NO;}

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler {
if (allowLoad == YES) {
    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
} else {
    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel);
}}
```

Now after this code, you'll not be able to open any link on the page that is opened.