# Prevent WKWebView From Being Able To Navigate To Specific Pages On A Website (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift, webkit

I am trying to prevent users from being able to navigate to different pages on a website by using WKNavigationDelegate and implementing the function below:

---

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if let urlStr = navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString {
            if urlStr == "https://random.ca/#/profile" {
                decisionHandler(.cancel)
                return
            }
        }
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
```

---

This function seems to only be called when I first load the home page of the website and when I navigate to other pages inside of this site it is not triggered and so I cannot prevent the user from navigating to those pages.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try removing "return". or remove the last part "decisionHandler(.allow)"

Comment: Thanks for your comment Jintor. Unfortunately, doing so did not fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found something

Just before calling `webView.load()`

add this

```
webView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

check this [Disable links in WKWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181813/disable-links-in-wkwebview) for more details